# Sorting rows with 2 episodes number in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, rows

I have a table that is something like this, but the problem is, whenever I try to set them in order based on their episode number from lowest to highest I get different results.

```
id   |    episode
1    (Title) Episode 1
2    (Title) Episode 4    
3    (Title) Episode 2    
4    (Title) Episode 5-6    
5    (Title) Episode 13   
6    (Title) Episode 3    
7    (Title) Episode 8-9    
8    (Title) Episode 7    
9    (Title) Episode 11-12    
10   (Title) Episode 10
```

I have tried this line **`ORDER BY LENGTH(`table`.episode),`table`.episode`** to order the episode. This works excellent, but if the episode title contains more episode number such as **Episode 5-6**, **Episode 8-9**, and **Episode 11-12** This rows will be shifted all the way to the bottom.

Here is the results I am getting

```
id   |    episode
1    (Title) Episode 1
2    (Title) Episode 2    
3    (Title) Episode 3           
4    (Title) Episode 4   
5    (Title) Episode 7  
6    (Title) Episode 10  
7    (Title) Episode 13
8    (Title) Episode 5-6     
9    (Title) Episode 8-9   
10   (Title) Episode 11-12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM test2
ORDER BY cast( substring_index( substring_index( title, ' ', -1 ) , '-', 1 ) AS decimal )
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, could you please try again?

Answer (score 0):

What is the Data type of the (EpisodeNumber), I believe it is varchar.
sorting by varchar is not recommended, I would create a new column with DataType int and sort by it. I am not sure if that is the solution you are looking for...

Comment: Nope, not what I am looking for